# Continuous map with $f(x)\in B(x,r)$ for every $x\in\Bbb{R}^2$ with some fixed $r>0$ is surjective

Tags: real-analysis, algebraic-topology

> Let $f:\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}^2$ be a continuous map such that there exists $r>0$ with $f(x)\in B(x,r)$ for every $x\in\Bbb{R}^2$. Show that $f$ is surjective.

---

I have some vague idea that if $p\not\in f(\Bbb{R}^2)$, one could somehow construct a retraction from $\Bbb{R^2}$ to $S^1$ via a homeomorphism between $\Bbb{R}^2\setminus\{p\}$ and $S^1$ so that one has a contradiction. I don't really see how to do it. Also is there a way to do it without explicitly using methods in algebraic topology?

Comment: If you could use algebraic topology, it's a duplicate of [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1538328/surjectivity-of-a-continuous-map-between-mathbbrds). Not sure if any sort of algebraic topological method can be avoided.

Comment: Maybe you wanted to say the homeomorphism between $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $S^2 \backslash \{ p \}$?

Answer (score 0):

If you allow homotopies to be used, then there is a way to do it without algebraic topology.

Just take the homotopy 
$$ H\colon \mathbb{R}^n\times I \to \mathbb{R}^n, \ (x,r) \mapsto rf(x)+ (1-r)x .$$
from $f$ to the identity of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then $H(x,i)\in B(x,r)$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $i\in I$. This condition ensures that we can extend this homotopy to $\mathbb{S}^n$.

It is easy to show that a non surjective self map of the sphere is null-homotopic. So if $f$ is not surjective, then the identity of $\mathbb{S}^n$ is null-homotopic.

If you use an [analytical proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1242352) of Brouwer's fixed point theorem to show that the sphere is not contractible, you have proven that $f$ is surjective without using homology or homotopy groups.